# Jenkins and Android Application

Tags: android, testing, mobile, jenkins, automation

I'm starting a project for my own benefit for work/college purposes.

Before I start I'm doing some planning.

At the moment I have Jenkins running automated test jobs.

What I want to do is to create a mobile application that I can use to monitor the tests that are being run via Jenkins.

Is this possible? Such as is it possible to connect an android application to a Jenkins job?

Hopefully it doesn't sound too stupid as I'm fairly new to all this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Some useful articles/tutorials would be hugely appreciated to get me started, especially ones that may be somewhat relevant to what I hope to achieve.

Comment: This link seems to describe it quite well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-android-apps-with-jenkins. It takes some setup, but it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Thank you very much. Much appreciated ! :)